# How prevent to auto change view of a folder icons in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons

In my windows 7 i want to set all folders view to **list**.
So i opened explorer and went to

> Tools -> Folder Options -> View

and pressed **Reset Folders** button and ok button.
After reset i went back to current folder and changed it's view to **list**.
After that i went back to

> Tools -> Folder Options -> View

and this time i pressed **Apply To Folders** button and ok button.
Ok, now i have all my folders in list mode view.
I have some folders in my desktop and and want to change their icons view to **Medium icons** and here is my problem.
when i change their view to Medium icons, it changes back to list automatically!
How can i keep those folders in Medium icons view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is something wrong about my q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  Highlight the folder(s)--right click on a highlighted folder--open properties--click the customize tab--select optimize this folder for pictures--click apply this template to all subfolders--click apply.

Hope this works for you.